# Graph the following curve

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Graph the following curve. Use Mathematica to find the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve about the indicated axis.
 = 1 + 3^2       = sin(2) cos (1/4 ) 0          <=  <= 1/2 ;        [Minus]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ParametricPlot3D[{ ( 1 + 3 t^2) Cos[teta], (1 + 3 t^2) Sin[teta],Sin[2 t] Cos[t/4]  }, {t, 0, 1/2}, {teta, 0, 2 Pi},Axes -> False , Boxed -> False ]
```

[image]

There is also a function `RevolutionPlot3D` which you might try.